# LISP nested Loops perform in parallel. How would one force it to perform sequentially?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, nested-loops, sequential

I have been slowly learning Lisp over the past 2 weeks. I have come across a situation where Lisp performs two Loops in parallel, and is not what I am aiming for. If I understand correctly, what I want to achieve would be categorized as sequentially. To give you an idea of what happens, we can take a look at the following:

```
(loop for x in '(a b c d e)
      for y in '(1 2 3 4 5)
        collect (list x y))
```

With this type of coding, one will get:

```
((A 1) (B 2) (C 3) (D 4) (E 5))
```

But what I am seeking is:

```
((A 1) (A 2) (A 3) (A 4) (A 5) (B 1) (B 2) (B 3) and so on
```

What would I need to change with the Loop to get this type of desired result?
If I am wrong in the usage of the term "sequentially", please correct me. I have been reading up on it, but I am having a bit of a hard time grasping this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need nested loops:

```
(loop for x in '(a b c d e)
      nconc (loop for y in '(1 2 3 4 5)
                  collect (list x y)))
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. Prompt, precise and professional.